# Verifying the text content of PDFs

Tags: pdf, search

My website has a file repository, that includes text search - it not only searches the files' titles, but also their set properties and contents.

The problem is, some of the files have not been saved correctly, and return really weird search results.

I have a project to go through and fix up the properties so they hopefully start displaying correctly in search, but it would be nice to check what the search system is likely to see before I re-upload and tell the website to re-scan the files.

To this end, I was wondering if anyone made a text-only preview of PDFs, the way my search engine might see it?  So that I can check the contents before I bother to re-upload the file?

Or is there some other method to check this, maybe?

Comment: i don't know how, but google docs APIs might be able to help in some way. i'll try to search a bit on this.

Answer (score 0):

The [pdftotext](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pdftotext.1.html) tool can extract the plain text from a PDF.